# Tool for monitoring Rails deployments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Do you know any tool for monitoring Rails application deployments ?
If we assume that we are using capistrano, we should know at least about time every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like this ? http://newrelic.com/

SaaS or Self-hosted ?

Regards,